# Route doesn't get displayed, after passing it the screen coordinates resulting from the clicks on Google Map, displayed on the Qt widget

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes, qwebview

And I am using Qt, so the map is shown on the widget.

Global variables:

```
    var arrayMarkers = new Array();
    var arrayIndex   = 0;
```

This function "gets" called and also "displays" markers on the map where I click. Also it duly calls the **displayRoute** function when I click the second time.

```
    function Open (x, y)
    {       
        google.maps.event.addListener (map, "click", 
                                function (event)
                                {
                                    alert("You clicked the map."+ event.latLng.toString(4));

                                    arrayMarkers [arrayIndex] = event.latLng;

                                    var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                                                    position:arrayMarkers [arrayIndex],
                                                                    draggable:false,
                                                                    map:map,
                                                                    flat:true
                                                                    }); 

                                    if (arrayIndex == 1)
                                    {
                                        displayRoute();
                                    }

                                    arrayIndex++;
                                });
    }
```

The alert is shown properly when the following **displayRoute** function gets called. But that's it, the **route** does **NOT** get displayed! The alert in the **directionsService.route** call is NOT shown, that means the function *directionsService.route* doesn't get even called? What to do? Please help.

```
    function displayRoute ()
     {
        alert ("displayRoute");
        var start = arrayMarkers [0];
        var end   = arrayMarkers [1];

        var request = {
                    origin:start,
                    destination:end,
                    travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    };


        directionsService.route (request, 
                            function (result, status) 
                            {
                                alert(status);
                                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                                {
                                    directionsDisplay.setDirections (result);

                                    pointsArray = result.routes[0].overview_path;

                                    var j = 0;

                                    for (j = 0; j < 49; j++)
                                    {
                                        var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                            position:pointsArray[j],
                                            draggable:true,
                                            map:map,
                                            flat:true
                                            });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had included some values in ***< script src >*** without knowing what they are

:banghead::banghead::banghead:

The original was:

`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I had modified it to:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.1&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Changing it back to normal displays the route!